Mikro ORM - How to sort by the appropriate field type on a json field?
I currently have a table with a json field on it, which we use to store metadata.
I have the following model:
@Embeddable()
class Meta {
  @Property({ nullable: true })
  foo: string

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  bar: number
}

@Entity()
class User {
  @Embedded(() => Meta, { object: true, nullable: true, type: 'json' })
  // Have also tried this
  // @Property({ type: () => Meta, nullable: true, columnType: 'json' })
  meta?: Meta

  ...
}

Now I wish to sort on meta.bar. When i do
em.find(User, { orderBy: { meta: { bar: 'asc' } } }, I get the following error:
2024-08-02 14:26:00     "DriverException: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')\n" +
2024-08-02 14:26:00       '    at PostgreSqlExceptionConverter.convertException (/usr/app/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/platforms/ExceptionConverter.js:8:16)\n' +
2024-08-02 14:26:00       '    at PostgreSqlExceptionConverter.convertException (/usr/app/node_modules/@mikro-orm/postgresql/PostgreSqlExceptionConverter.js:42:22)\n' +
2024-08-02 14:26:00       '    at PostgreSqlDriver.convertException (/usr/app/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/drivers/DatabaseDriver.js:197:54)\n' +
2024-08-02 14:26:00       '    at /usr/app/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/drivers/DatabaseDriver.js:201:24\n' +

If I just use a plain old json Field, it will resort back to ordering by string. How can i make mikro orm aware of what data types are used on my json field? Thanks.

What if you remove the type: 'json' from the embedded definition? I guess it could confuse the ORM. It should be just @Embedded(() => Meta, { object: true, nullable: true }).

Did a quick test and it works fine on my end with such entity definition, even with the additional type: 'json'.

Uh oh.. I anonymised + simplified the setup I'm working with, I wonder if I ended up 'simplifying' the issue out, or maybe its config related..? Simply swapping the type back to Property lets the sort work, removed the json type too to no avail.. I've stripped down the find to use no filter {}, and options are stripped back too. No groupbys, filters, orderby, only fetching meta field, and the exception still occurs..  Looks like the error comes from const right = ${join.alias}.${join.joinColumns[idx]}`` in QueryBuilderHelper, maybe its a join config?

What version are you on?

We're still on v5 (5.8.0) core. We have a few blockers preventing us from upping to 6. Would an upgrade fix this? I can give 6+ a whack, and hopefully it'll compile to test it out even with breaking changes.

Yes, this is most likely something already fixed in v6. Next time mention this right ahead that you not using latest version.
